# Implementing Vue on Existing Site Issue

Tags: vue.js

We have an existing website. We'd like to add Vue to areas of the site. Some areas we'd only need a single Vue app to run like a shopping cart. Other areas we'd have multiple of the same component on the page broken up by non Vue items. We'd also like to use single .vue files for our building. I can't for the life of me figure out the best way to do this.

If we use the CLI to build individual apps, we can of course bring those apps in on the pages and where needed. However on the pages where we have the same component separated by non Vue items, it seems we'd need the exact same app multiple times and compiled this doesn't seem to work.

Whats the best route to do this. I'd like to just add a global wrapper to my site, compile a single APP and then house all logic inside components. This breaks down as it replaces my existing content with the app's content when it's a compiled app. I can on the core layout page just instantiate an app and that works, but then I can't use single file components.

Am I missing something. I'd like to use single file components, have a global wrapper on my site with existing content used and components only where needed, AND not have to import each component file one by one.

We cannot use WC builds either as we can't drop IE 11.